# How to detect if a player has no item selected in his hand?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So, in version 1.12 we can easily detect if a player has nothing selected in his hand by just using the nbt `{SelectedItem:{}}`.

I realise that it is no longer working in version 1.13 +. I tried to replace it with `{nbt=SelectedItem:{id:“”}}`, but it does not work. Does anyone know how to solve it? I'm currently working on an Antman function datapack, I really need that command to make it functionable.

Comment: Those quotation marks would not work anyway.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `nbt` in your target selector in 1.13+. The `SelectedItem` tag will not be present in a player who doesn't have a selected item.

This command would teleport every player holding an item to your position:

```
/tp @a[nbt={SelectedItem:{}}] ~ ~ ~
```

To teleport them to your position when they don't hold an item you can use a `!` to negate the result, basically telling you if the player does not have a selected item:

```
/tp @a[nbt=!{SelectedItem:{}}] ~ ~ ~
```

Comment: Ohhh thats a clever way to do it. I dont even think about that. Thanks bro!